# Defining a variable used later in the SELECT Teradata query

Tags: sql, variables, teradata

I have a problem with defining a variable that I will later refer to in the SQL query. I do it on Teradata. I have specific code where a given column must include these values.

```
var_1 = ('x1', 'x2', 'x3', etc.)
```

how to define it in the Teradata code to refer to this variable later in the select query, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE key in var_1
```

This variable var_1 will appear often in the code, so I want to define it in only one place.

Comment: If you have a function like string_split() in teradata you can write a subquery after IN like " SELECT value FROM  string_split(@var_1 ',',')". You will have to declare your var_1 as string though.

Comment: The equivalent function would be `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` but you can't assign values to variables in Teradata SQL - text substitution would need to be done on the client side, in which case there is no need for a function call. Otherwise create a VOLATILE table and INSERT the values, then reference the table in the IN (SELECT ...) clause or just do a JOIN.

Comment: You can set the variable in the session's queryband: `SET QUERY_BAND = 'var_1=x1,x2,x3;' UPDATE FOR SESSION VOLATILE;`  and then retrieve it using `GetQueryBandValueSF(0, 'var_1')`. To pass multiple values you need to split it into rows like Fred suggested. And to use it multiple time you wrap everything in a CTE.